# Use of new in C++

Tags: c++

Let's assume I pass a new object to a function like this:

```
loadContainer->addControlView( new BmpView( BMP_PICTURE ) );
```

Now, I want to change a specific characteristic of the BmpView before I pass it to addControlView. The way I do this is like this:

```
Control* newView = new BmpView( BMP_PICTURE );
newView->changeColor( WHITE );
loadContainer->addControlView( newView );
```

Does this create an extra temporary/local object? Or is there an equal amount of memory allocated in both cases?

Comment: Depends on what `changeColor` returns.

Comment: changeColor is a void.

Comment: Short answer: Yes, this uses the same amount of memory (unless changeColor() allocates memory, but it still would be inside the BmpView object). You could use a tool like valgrind to find out if you have a memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only added memory allocated in your function is a new pointer `*newView`, which its size is pretty low and doesn't affect by the actual size of the BmpView. It doesn't allocate twice memory for BmpView.

I'm not considering any memory overhead of calling `changeColor`, which I assume wasn't the point of this question.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, there is single call to `new`, hence the amount of memory used is equal. (Note, this is without speculating about any allocation possibly requested by `BmpView` constructor, `changeColor()`, etc.)

However, you may wish to refactor your code to ensure some exception safety, avoid potential leaks hence ensure the amount of memory used is under control:

```
// C++11
std::unique_ptr<Control> newView(new BmpView(BMP_PICTURE));
// C++14, preferred
//auto newView = std::make_unique<BmpView>(BMP_PICTURE);
newView->changeColor( WHITE );
loadContainer->addControlView( newView.release() );
```

Answer (score 2):

Reference for the below code/assembly : 
https://godbolt.org/g/8DgmC1

```
#include <cstdio>

class ValueClass {
    public:
    // Class content not important...
    int someValue;
};

void PrintValueClass(ValueClass* ptr) {
    printf("%d\n", ptr->someValue);
}

int main() {

    PrintValueClass(new ValueClass());
    ValueClass* pValueClass = new ValueClass();
    pValueClass->someValue = 55;
    PrintValueClass(pValueClass);

return 1;
}
```

Compiled Assembly (PrintValueClass redacted as not important to question at hand) :

Example where you pass the (new ValueClass) directly to the function.

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     edi, 4
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 0
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    PrintValueClass(ValueClass*)
        mov     eax, 1
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Example where you create a local variable holding the pointer, do something to it, and then pass it to the function.

```
 main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     edi, 4
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 0
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 55
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    PrintValueClass(ValueClass*)
        mov     eax, 1
        leave
        ret
```

Before diving into the assembly, if your question is does the new operation occur twice if you store the pointer in a variable first, the answer is no. As shown through the assembly, the new 'function' is only called once, so only sizeof(ValueClass) is ever being allocated here through some sort of heap allocation function. But I feel the need to answer the question fully, even if it was not exactly intended to ask this question. Is extra memory used? Technically yes, realistically no.

The only difference between these two pieces of code is stack 'allocation', noted by the `sub rsp, 16`, which essentially means 'allocate' 16 bytes on the stack for local variables. So truly the only difference here is 16 bytes, which will greatly change on what compiler you use, what architecture you target, and many more factors.

At the end of the day, I would go as far to say, you would never care about the extra 16 bytes.